# [Oracle][ODBC][Ora]ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected

Tags: oracle, asp-classic

I kind a new in oracle i got problem that i cannot solve
my script is

```
sql = "`Select TOP "& myTops &" * FROM Employee INNER JOIN Employee_Ext ON Employee.StaffNo = Employee_Ext.StaffNo where Employee.staffDepart like '" & Depart & "%' order by Employee.staffname`"

    set myDd = connISAS.execute(sql)
```

Error - `[Oracle][ODBC][Ora]ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected`

Can anyone kindly tell me what I'm missing?

Comment: Oracle does not support the TOP keyword

Comment: `TOP` is not Oracle keyword. What is you Oracle version. You could use `ROWNUM`. In `12C`, you could use `TOP-N` query using `FETCH FIRST n ROWS ONLY`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to play with ROWNUM as TOP is meaningless in oracle.

[Rownum help](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/issue-archive/2006/06-sep/o56asktom-086197.html)